# c++: argv contains some spaces

Tags: c++, windows, parameters, space, argv

I want to pass only ONE parameter containing some spaces to my function main. Here is an example:

```
string param = "{\"abc\" \"de\"}"; // the string is {"abc" "de"}
boost::replace_all(param, "\"", "\\\""); // now it becomes: {\"abc\" \"de\"}
boost::replace_all(param, " ", "\\40");  // now it becomes: {\"abc\"\40\"de\"}

ShellExecute(GetDesktopWindow(), "open", "myMainTest.exe", param.c_str(), "", SW_SHOWNORMAL); // execute my function main in another project
```

// in the function main of myMainTest.exe

```
cout<<argv[1];
```

I got this result:

```
{"abc"\40"de"}
```

It means that the double quote is OK but the space is not.

Comment: FYI If you use a [raw string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) (`R""`) then you do not need to escape quotes.

Comment: Doesn't this work? `string param = "{\"abc de\"}";`

Comment: Congrats, as it seems it works. Output in the program is exactly what you pass to it. So what exactly is your question? Do you want to pass something else? Then go ahead and do so.

Comment: @Roddy   No. If I do like this, the function will regard it as two parameters.

Comment: @Thomas. I don't think so. Read here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17w5ykft.aspx

Comment: @Roddy   well, u see, there are always 3 parameters.

Comment: @WernerHenze   I want to pass one parameter containing some spaces. that's all.

Comment: string param = "\"abc def\"".  The trick is to encapsulate the desired entire parameter containing space in embedded quotes. Note each (\").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, this is directly tied to the way windows processes its command line. Arguments are normally splitted on spaces with the exception that strings enclosed in double quotes (`"`) are processed as a single parameter after removing quotes.

But it is far from the way Unix-like shells processes input! No simple and direct way to escape a quote itself. But as your quotes are balanced it will work. Here is the actual string that you must pass to `ShellExecute`: `"{\"abc\" \"def\"}"`. Now only remains how to write that is C++ source:

```
string param = "\"{\\\"abc\\\" \\\"def\\\"}\"";
ShellExecute(GetDesktopWindow(), "open", "myMainTest.exe", param.c_str(), "", SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

And `myMainTest.exe` should see only single parameter: `{"abc" "def"}`

Comment: One technical point: it isn't Windows that is processing the command line that way, but the C runtime library linked to myMainTest.exe.  You could, if you wished, modify myMainTest.exe to parse the command line in any way you preferred.